# Angular - Iteration doesn´t work (only take first)

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a array and i want to iterate all elements. The problem is simple: ngFor does not iterate all array, only takes the first element.

The code is:

TS

```
 alertas: any;

 this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    if (this.id) {
      this.graphCtrl.getMeter(this.id).subscribe(
        response => {;
          this.alertas = response["body"]["alarmasActivas"];
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
```

HTML

```
   <ol id="firstLink" class="collapse " *ngFor="let alert of alertas">
        <li>{{alert.id}} ({{alert.fechaInicio |  date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}} - {{alert.fechaFin |  date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}})</li>
   </ol>
```

Array

```
body:
alarmasActivas: Array(8)
0: {id: 161, fechaInicio: 1561717685225, fechaFin: null, alarma: null, idDatameter: 6}
1: {id: 162, fechaInicio: 1561717685227, fechaFin: null, alarma: null, idDatameter: 6}
2: {id: 163, fechaInicio: 1561717685229, fechaFin: null, alarma: null, idDatameter: 6}
3: {id: 164, fechaInicio: 1561717685230, fechaFin: null, alarma: null, idDatameter: 6}
4: {id: 165, fechaInicio: 1561717685230, fechaFin: null, alarma: null, idDatameter: 6}
5: {id: 166, fechaInicio: 1561717685231, fechaFin: null, alarma: null, idDatameter: 6}
6: {id: 167, fechaInicio: 1561717685232, fechaFin: null, alarma: null, idDatameter: 6}
7: {id: 168, fechaInicio: 1561717685233, fechaFin: null, alarma: null, idDatameter: 6}
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)
consumoMedioDiario: "0,000"
```

JSON.stringfy

```
[{"id":161,"fechaInicio":1561717685225,"fechaFin":null,"alarma":null,"idDatameter":6},{"id":162,"fechaInicio":1561717685227,"fechaFin":null,"alarma":null,"idDatameter":6},{"id":163,"fechaInicio":1561717685229,"fechaFin":null,"alarma":null,"idDatameter":6},{"id":164,"fechaInicio":1561717685230,"fechaFin":null,"alarma":null,"idDatameter":6},{"id":165,"fechaInicio":1561717685230,"fechaFin":null,"alarma":null,"idDatameter":6},{"id":166,"fechaInicio":1561717685231,"fechaFin":null,"alarma":null,"idDatameter":6},{"id":167,"fechaInicio":1561717685232,"fechaFin":null,"alarma":null,"idDatameter":6},{"id":168,"fechaInicio":1561717685233,"fechaFin":null,"alarma":null,"idDatameter":6}]
```

So, what it´s wrong in this code?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: What is wrong is that you create a brand new ordered list with the same ID every time (although an ID is supposed to be unique) for every alert you get. The ngFor must be on the li, not on the ol. It's the li that must be repeated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use `*ngFor` with `<li>` instead of `<ol>`. Earlier you were creating a different list for each element of the array. with the updated code, you will have 1 list for all the elements of array

```
<ol id="firstLink" class="collapse " >
    <li *ngFor="let alert of alertas">
        {{alert.id}} ({{alert.fechaInicio |  date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}} - {{alert.fechaFin |  date:'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}})
    </li>
</ol>
```